# How to use zsh shell when debugging in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, nvm, vscode-debugger

I run different node versions to build different web apps on my machine. I use nvm to manage the environments.

I set the integrated terminal in VS Code for `osx` to zsh as so:

```
  "terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/zsh",
```

In the integrated terminal It appears to be running `zsh`, my nvm config runs etc.

But when I run the **VS Code Debugger** it doesn't pick up my nvm version.

When I run `echo $SHELL` in the integrated terminal I get `/bin/bash` even though it appears to be running `/bin/zsh`. In iTerm2 i get `/bin/zsh` as expected.

I need the debugger to run in `zsh` so that the nvm config is picked up and the build step is run in the correct node version. Otherwise node-sass has a fit etc and my debugging environment is out of whack with dev and prod.

How can I get the VS Code dubugger to run in `zsh`?

BTW: I am using the chrome debugger extension which appears to disallow the out-the-box node version debugger config such as `"runtimeVersion": "9.4.0"`.

Comment: Have the same problem it is annoying that changing: "console": "externalTerminal" in launch.json and "terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/zsh",
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.osx": [], does not work...

Comment: I'm facing this issue myself now...

Answer (score 0):

Add next to your `settings.json`, respecting your OS.
This covers both normal and debug terminals

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
    "zsh": {
      "path": "zsh",
      "args": []
    }
  },
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh"
```

Answer (score 0):

I still have this problem in 2023 but in the opposite direction, in that I use bash instead of MacOS's default zsh. I solved this by simlinking my bash `.profile` to `.zshrc` and restarting vscode.

```bash
ln -s ~/.profile ~/.zshrc
```